# Proof that the Chinese restaurant process corresponds to Dirichlet process?

Tags: bayesian, stochastic-processes, nonparametric-bayes

Let $(S, \mathcal{S})$ be a Polish space. Is there a nice proof of the fact that if the people are seated in a restaurant according to Chinese restaurant process, and then for each table, we sample a dish independently from $S$ according to a probability distribution $G(.)$ on $(S, \mathcal{S})$. Then, this is equivalent to sampling a probability distribution $P(.)$ on $(S, \mathcal{S})$ from a Dirichlet process $DP(\alpha, G(.))$, and then subsequently sampling the dishes from $P(.)$.